# Not able to install phonegap on my office mac with latest node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova

I am not able to install phonegap  using npm install on my offcial mac under a corporate network. I have set the proxy in npm config, the problem is something else attching the log below :

> sudo npm install -g phonegap npm ERR! not a package
>   /tmp/npm-6304-096fadf6/github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz
>   npm ERR! not a package
>   /tmp/npm-6304-096fadf6/github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz
>   npm ERR! not a package
>   /tmp/npm-6304-096fadf6/github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz
>   npm ERR! not a package
>   /tmp/npm-6304-096fadf6/github.com/component/bind/archive/0.0.1.tar.gz
>
> > ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> >     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
>
> /| npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"}
>   (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"}) npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4:
>   wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"}) npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1:
>   wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"}) npm WARN installMany
>   normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package
>   wasn't found in unpacked tree npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0 npm ERR! argv
>   "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap" npm ERR! node
>   v0.12.3 npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1 npm ERR! path
>   /tmp/npm-6304-096fadf6/unpack-261cc60a6ec0/package.json npm ERR! code
>   ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open
>   '/tmp/npm-6304-096fadf6/unpack-261cc60a6ec0/package.json' npm ERR!
>   enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR!
>   enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR!
>   enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/admin/npm-debug.log

any pointers on how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried to install with `sudo`?

Comment: @vanadium23 yes this is with sudo

Comment: Follow the official guide : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface